# Over which timespan audiences are evaluated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I have an audience that looks like:

Count of (Event MEDIA_HALBUM with action exactly matches "add") is greater than 0

My understanding is that when I show the graph of the audience, the count is done over the data of the time period I have selected in the view.

But when I use it in a Cloud Messaging, which timespan is taken? In other words, how many days in the past firebase goes to count the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en):

> Once created, an audience accumulates users who meet the specified criteria from that point onward by virtue of the events that their devices log.